# Class, variable, type and object

Tags: java

вчем разница между variable, object,type and class

Comment: А литературу по Java вы уже читали?

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример кода:

```
public class Dog{
   String breed;
   int age;
   String color;
}
```

`Dog` - это класс (`class`)

`String`, `int` - это типы (`type`)

`breed`, `age`, `color` - это переменные (`variable`)

А объект - это переменная, появляющаяся при создании экземпляра класса.

```
Dog poodle;
```

`poodle` - Объект класса `Dog`.

Я постарался максимально просто, на примере, объяснить что это, но советую почитать книжку по java для начинающих

Comment: `Dog` еще и тип (так же как `String еще и класс).

Comment: И не переменные, а поля. Переменная она тогда, когда в методе

Comment: *poodle - Объект класса Dog* тоже не совсем верно.

Comment: Я знаю, но не хочу слишком много информации давать за раз, чтобы он не запутался. Для всех этих уточнений я предложил ему почитать литературу.